# neotree: `all-the-icons-icon-for-dir` raises void-function error

Tags: debugging, neotree

I am getting an error with neotree and i dont know why the arguments from call-interactively are nil.

Edit: The Problem is within neotree and i have an empty init file just with neotree and the Problem occurs when i switch to the root directory.

Backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function nil)
nil()
apply(nil nil) 
all-the-icons-icon-for-dir("/" "right") 
neo-buffer--insert-fold-symbol(close "/") 
neo-buffer--insert-root-entry("/") 
neo-buffer--insert-tree("/" 1) 
neo-buffer--refresh(nil) 
neo-buffer--change-root("/") 
neo-global--open-dir("/") 
neotree-dir("/") 
funcall-interactively(neotree-dir "/")
call-interactively(neotree-dir) 
neotree-change-root() 
funcall-interactively(neotree-change-root)
call-interactively(neotree-change-root nil nil) 
command-execute(neotree-change-root)
```

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You may wish to start your tracing/debugging by looking at the function `all-the-icons-match-to-alist` within `all-the-icons.el`:  https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/blob/master/all-the-icons.el  Apparently, that function cannot handle the root directory of `"/"` or `all-the-icons-icon-for-dir` needs to be fixed to deal with a situation when the former returns `nil`.  You may wish to open an issue with the maintainers of that library on Github.  I do not see this as a `neotree` problem per se.